# Python. Как "нарисовать" значок суммы при выводе суммы чисел на экран?

Tags: python, математика

Необходимо создать GUI приложение, где будут вычисляться различные суммы чисел. С этим проблем нет. Однако, есть проблема с красивым выводом информации на экран.

Например, вычисляется натуральный ряд 1+2+3

В результате, хочется увидеть не просто S = 6, а греческий значок Суммы, то есть СИГМА. Внутри сигмы то, что складывали, вверху и внизу - от чего складывали и до чего соответственно

Подскажите, для этого надо использовать какой-то символ ASCII?

Как запрограммировать такой значок?

Comment: Σ? Может быть вам нужна [таблица математических символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode)?

Comment: Да, именно этот значок. Однако, при применении таблицы, не удается внизу сигмы написать от чего меняется 'n', а наверху сигмы - до чего меняется 'n'...

Comment: Мне кажется здесь проще не искать символы индексов и степеней, хотя такие есть - ₂2², а просто добавить сверху и снизу две текстовые метки в которые будут устанавливаться нужные значения.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что-то вроде 
print('x = 10')
print('\u2a0C f(x) dx = ', 5)
print('x = 0')

Comment: Но там границы жутко выходят за рамки тройного интеграла к примеру

Comment: Нет, не через `print()`. Вы же написали в вопросе про GUI, а там проде как можно по пикселям подогнать расположение в нужное место. Если вы пишете на tkinter, то у вас будет 3 текст. метки `Label` - одна с "Σ", две другие - со значениями.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!